# Как реализовать пролистывание кодом в textbox wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Я добавляю кодом в текстбокс TxtMain новые строчки кодом. В один прекрасный момент их становится слишком много, они не помещаются, появляются полосы прокрутки. Но прокрутка не осуществляется автоматически.
Как можно сделать, что, когда строчки не помещаются, осуществлялась прокрутка на самую нижнюю автоматически (из кода), чтобы пользователю не приходилось мотать самому?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внезапно вам нужна функция [TextBoxBase.ScrollToEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.scrolltoend.aspx), она перематывает в конец.